# Como obtener valor de una variable de php en javascript distintos archivos

Tags: javascript, php, html5

Tengo el siguiente código en un archivo PHP:

```js
function Iniciar ()
{
  var a =  ('<? echo $variable; ?>');
  alert (a);
}
```

```html
<?php 
  $variable = '3';
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
  <button onclick="Iniciar ()">apachame</button>
</body>
</html>

<script type="text/javascript" src="prueba.js"></script>
```

Y en un archivo por aparte tengo el js pero lo que obtengo es el texto de la variable `a` y no su valor `'<? echo $variable; ?>'`. No se como puedo hacer para que reconozca el codigo de php en javascript en diferentes archivos, ya que si hago el script en el mismo archivo de php si me lo reconoce pero lo quiero hacer por aparte.

Comment: si lo que quieres es obtener el valor de una variable de PHP con JS debes usar o bien Jquery y colocar el valor de la variable de php como atributo en una etiqueta html o debes usar  include('nombreDelArchivoPHP.php') para que te reconozca las variables de otros archivos php, deberias mostrar tambien tu script JS para guiarnos y saber cual camino deseas.

Comment: Pero la etiqueta para codigo php es `<?php` no es solo `<?`... No será ese el problema?

Comment: ya probe asi y tampoco funciona

Comment: @Pipe es una sintaxis abreviada que se puede usar. <? ...  ?> es lo mismo que <?php ... ?> , también <?= 'hola' ?> es lo mismo que <?php echo 'hola' ?>. Esto se debe configurar en el php.ini

Answer (score 0):

No se puede hacer lo que tú quieres. PHP imprime sobre el documento mismo, no sobre los otros elementos externos que componen el HTML (js, css, imagenes, etc).

Si es posible crear un PHP como script.js, pero es mucho lio para lo que tú quieres. A mi parecer lo más fácil es colocar tu dato en una variable global.

```
<? 
    $variable = '3';
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <button onclick="Iniciar ()">apachame</button>
</body>
</html>

<script>
   const a =  '<? echo $variable; ?>'; //mal nombre para la variable, pero bueno supongo que es un ejemplo 
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="prueba.js"></script>
```

Y luego en tu `prueba.js``

```
function Iniciar ()
{
  alert (a);
}
```